# How to set all counters to dozenal system?

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

I would like to page number my document using base 12 but also to number AMS theorems, sections, equations… the same way.
What would be the best solution?

I found this working code to use binary for page numbering:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\thepage{\int_to_bin:n{\value{page}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Maybe should I use the dozenal package in some way.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\btwelve#1{\expandafter\@btwelve\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@btwelve#1{\ifnum#1>11
\@btwelve{\numexpr(#1-6)/12\relax}%
\btwelvedigits{\numexpr#1-((#1-6)/12)*12\relax}\else
\btwelvedigits{#1}%
\fi}

\def\btwelvedigits#1{\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax 0\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9\or A\or B\or[\number#1]\fi}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\thepage{\btwelve{page}}

\setcounter{page}{5} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{10} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{11} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{12} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{17} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{18} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{19} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{24} \thepage

\setcounter{page}{25} \thepage

}
\end{document}
```

This can easily be adapted to any base *just replace 11, 12 and 6 in the calculation).

Answer (score 5):

Same idea as in the question using a flexible base:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\thepage{\int_to_Base:nn{\value{page}}{12}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Do you know how to extend this to AMS theorems counters?

Answer (score 4):

`\usepackage[typeone]{dozenal}` will do that for you: all standard counters are redefined to use the special symbols (compatible with Computer Modern fonts).

Comment: Thanks! It works very well for standard counters but nor for AMS theorems.